# How to create value in dictionary by user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function that creates a request for a client to send to my server.
The client gets a menu and for each option, the function will create a request to send to the server, but for some of the options must involve input from the user, I tried to make a dictionary that has 8 keys and the value of some of them is - "input()".
The problem is that if I do that it asking once for input for all the keys, but I want to create value only for a specific key.
Here is what I tried:

```
def input():
    print("1 - Albums list\n2 - List of songs in a album\n3 - Get song length")
    print("4- Get lyrics song\n5 - Which album is the song in?")
    print("6 - Search Song by Name\n7 - Search Song by Lyrics in Song\n8 - Exit")
    request_creator(input())

def request_creator(x):
    return {'1': "1#", '2': "2#" + input("Enter album: "), '3': "3#" + input("Enter song: "), '4': "4#" + input("Enter song: "), '5': "5#" + input("Enter song: "), '6': "6#" + input("Enter a word: "), '7': "7#" + input("Enter lyrics: "), '8': "8#"}[x]
```

When the user asks for option number 3, for example, it will ask him also for all the others values but I need only for key number 3.
Is there any way to do that without a lot of if statements?

Comment: The expressions are being evaluated **before** being added to the dictionary, hence the unwanted prompts. Store only the prompt *strings* instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I recommend choosing a different name for your `input` function. If you want to keep using the builtin `input`, then you must not overwrite its name with your own function. How about `get_input` instead?

One way to prevent your dictionary from calling all your `input`s right away is to wrap each value in a lambda. This makes each value an anonymous function object, and none of them will execute unless you call them explicitly.

```
def get_input():
    print("1 - Albums list\n2 - List of songs in a album\n3 - Get song length")
    print("4- Get lyrics song\n5 - Which album is the song in?")
    print("6 - Search Song by Name\n7 - Search Song by Lyrics in Song\n8 - Exit")
    x = request_creator(input())
    print(x)

def request_creator(x):
    return {
        '1': lambda: "1#", 
        '2': lambda: "2#" + input("Enter album: "), 
        '3': lambda: "3#" + input("Enter song: "), 
        '4': lambda: "4#" + input("Enter song: "), 
        '5': lambda: "5#" + input("Enter song: "), 
        '6': lambda: "6#" + input("Enter a word: "), 
        '7': lambda: "7#" + input("Enter lyrics: "), 
        '8': lambda: "8#"
    }[x]()

get_input()
```

Result:

```
1 - Albums list
2 - List of songs in a album
3 - Get song length
4- Get lyrics song
5 - Which album is the song in?
6 - Search Song by Name
7 - Search Song by Lyrics in Song
8 - Exit
3
Enter song: hey jude
3#hey jude
```

---

If you don't feel comfortable with lambdas, you can instead store just the text of each prompt in a dictionary (or None if the option requires no prompt). Then you can fetch that string and call `input` with it (or skip calling `input` entirely).

```
def get_input():
    print("1 - Albums list\n2 - List of songs in a album\n3 - Get song length")
    print("4- Get lyrics song\n5 - Which album is the song in?")
    print("6 - Search Song by Name\n7 - Search Song by Lyrics in Song\n8 - Exit")
    x = request_creator(input())
    print(x)

def request_creator(x):
    prompts = {
        '1': None,
        '2': "Enter album: ",
        '3': "Enter song: ",
        '4': "Enter song: ",
        '5': "Enter song: ",
        '6': "Enter a word: ",
        '7': "Enter lyrics: ",
        '8': None
    }
    result = x + "#"
    prompt = prompts[x]
    if prompt is not None:
        result += input(prompt)
    return result

get_input()
```